# How Can I get the model properties using T4 template

Tags: reflection, t4, t4scaffolding

I am using T4Scaffolding, and tried to create a custom Scaffold template. It's not asp.net project, not MVC.

My user class :

```
   public class User
   {
     public int Id {get;set;}
     public string Name {get; set;}
   }
```

in the .cs.t4 file , I need to get the user properties ,I tried to use:

```
var propertyInfos = typeof(Model.).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public |
                                              BindingFlags.Static);
foreach (PropertyInfo propertyInfo in propertyInfos)
```

...

but It did not work, I know in asp.net mvc I can use

```
foreach (ModelProperty property in GetModelProperties(Model.ViewDataType, false))
```

What's the correct method in asp.net ???

Thanks for any comment ...

Comment: Maybe this question might be useful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7558809/reflection-with-t4-templates

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are passing a model with property `ViewDataType` you can get the properties of the type using the following code:

```
var modelType = (EnvDTE.CodeType) Model.ViewDataType;
var modelProperties = modelType.VisibleMembers().OfType<EnvDTE.CodeProperty>();
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Hi, How to fet Model , Is I need to add any external reference in my Create.cs.t4 file.