# Reflection with T4 Templates

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, templates, t4

I have a model class called `VideoGame`. I need the class to get passed in a t4 template using reflection in this method.

```
MethodInfo[] methodInfos =
    typeof(type).GetMethods(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static);
```

I have the following variables.

```
//passed via powershell file - is a string "VideoGame"
var modelName = Model.modelName
Type type = modelName.GetType();
```

I get an error that says: The type or namespace name 'type' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?). What I need to know is how to pass the VideoGame class inside that typeof() method. I have tried the following:

```
MethodInfo[] methodInfos =
    typeof(modelName.GetType()).GetMethods(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static);
MethodInfo[] methodInfos =
    modelName.GetType.GetMethods(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static);
MethodInfo[] methodInfos =
    typeof(modelName).GetMethods(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

typeof(modelName.GetType()) would never work, because modelName.GetType() returns a System.String's runtime type.

modelName.GetType has the same problem.

typeof(modelName) won't work because modelName is a string and typeof expects a Type.

So....if you have a string "VideoGame" and you want to get the methods on the Type VideoGame....

I would do:

```
Type.GetType(modelName).GetMethods()
```

Type.GetType will return a Type by the specified name. NOTE that this requires an Assembly Qualified Name....so just supplying VideoGame isn't enough. You need modelName to be in the form:

```
MyNamespace.VideoGame, MyAssemblyThatContainsVideoGame
```

Further, that means that whatever is running your T4 code needs to have a reference to MyAssemblyThatContainsVideoGame.

Comment: ok, when I pass in the assembly (same as the namespace) I get: Project.Games' is a 'namespace', which is not valid in the given context

Comment: Can you provide exact code? I would imagine you having something like Type.GetType(string.Format("{0}, {1}", modelName, modelName.Split('.')[0]))

Comment: Wait...you're trying to get the list of methods in the code GENERATOR, not the GENERATED CODE, right?

Comment: var modelName = Model.modelName;
    var AssemblyName = Project.Games.dll;
    MethodInfo[] methodInfos = Type.GetType(modelName).GetMethods(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static);

Comment: var AssemblyName = Project.Games.dll; doesn't make sense...try var assemblyName = "Project.Games"; and var methods = Type.GetType(string.Format("{1}.{0}, {1}", modelName, assemblyName).GetMethods(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static)

Comment: that should end up calling Type.GetType("Project.Games.VideoGame, Project.Games"). If that's not the Assembly Qualified Name of your type, there is something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass the name as string use [Activator.CreateInstance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d133hta4.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

The import of the classes in a T4 template is pretty awkward. I had this problem too and found it easier to write a console program that simply references the assembly where the classes are in, and puts out everything on the console. A text file can be created just as easily of course.